# HTML escape only some characters and combination of characters?

Tags: php, html

I'm managing a blog where a select few people can submit their own articles and entries. I want them to be able to embed video via HTML (and bold, italicize, etc text at their choosing). How do I do this while maintaining site security?

If I don't HTML escape the actual article space, an open comment will ruin my site. Is there a way to selectively escape some combination of characters?

edit; hopefully without writing my own parser. I just want simple things like `<b>`, `<i>`, etc tags unescaped, as well as video and link embedding.

Comment: You don't say what language you're using, but chances are that you're not going to have to write your own parser.  HTML parsing is a solved problem and packages abound to do it for you.

Comment: I've tagged the question as PHP and HTML.

Comment: Then start here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use what SO uses. it is opensource and has parsers for many languages.

The name is *WMD* and the question [*"Where's the WMD editor open source project?"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71822/wheres-the-wmd-editor-open-source-project) has some QA material outlining this editor.

The question [*"running showdown.js serverside to conver Markdown to HTML (in PHP)"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724218/running-showdown-js-serverside-to-conver-markdown-to-html-in-php) has some QA material outlining some Markdown libraries in PHP.

Comment: Take care: To run this in a safe manner, you need server-side execution of the javascript code, e.g. via node.js *or* you must have something compatbile in PHP, like a markdown library that works similar to the javascript code of that extension. It might be useful to add this second part to the answer as well.

Comment: @hakre - markdown is common enough all languages have parsers for it. fairly easy finding one. I will add in the answer the link to the PHP one

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this that most sites (such as SO) use is to introduce your own special markup, which is then translated into the features that you want.

For example, SO uses asterisks (`*`) to italicize and (`**`) bold (Edit: next to the HTML tags **`<b></b>`** itself, see source of this answer).

Other sites use `[b]` and `[i]` tags. You could have a `[video=http://myvideo.com]` tag, which your PHP then translates into the appropriate HTML entity.

Comment: SO has no special markup, it *allows* HTML tags (as per the Markdown specification btw.) So you are not answering any of the posed questions, instead I suggest for learning more, continue here: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/programming-is-hard-lets-go-shopping.html

Comment: It absolutely has special markup. The fact that HTML is supported alongside it does not negate this.

Comment: Well, it does not negate this, however it makes your answer being not one. You removed the problem by pointing to special markup which apparently in the given example allows HTML tags the author *is* concerned about with the question.

Comment: I don't understand your point. The fact that markup exists which does allow these tags doesn't mean that the author has to allow them as well. Regardless, he updated his question saying that he doesn't want to write a parser, so it's moot now.

Comment: Consider your stackoverflow example. Now imagine there is a user making use of stackoverflow only entering the special HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely HTML escape everything. URL's for your videos will be unaffected by whatever escaping you want to do.